# Open graph story is not visible in time line after posting

Tags: facebook-opengraph, android-facebook

I am using Facebook android SDK version 4.3.0. I want post my stories via open graph story method. This is my code.

```
`ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
        .putString("og:type", "mygame.life")
        .putString("og:title", "Sample Game")
        .putString("og:description", "sample game to publish story")
        .build();

ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
        .setActionType("mygame.ask")
        .putObject("life", object)
        .build();

ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
        .setPreviewPropertyName("life")
        .setAction(action)
        .build();

shareDialog.show(activity,content);`
```

It's working and also returns post Id. But there is no stories in my timeline.  How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you done all nesssary steps

- [give(request) `publish_actions`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph)
- [create and review action and object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/opengraph)

Comment: Eventually i found my mistake. I didn't enable "Tag" option in "Action Type" (Its essential to use setPeopleIds(peopleIds)) and also gave my app's name space wrongly.

Thank you @Aram

Answer (score 0):

Eventually i found my mistake. I didn't enable "Tag" option in "Action Type" (Its essential to use `setPeopleIds(peopleIds)`) and also gave my app's name space wrongly.